# How I can get a simple query multimatch text in SQL in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

How I can get this simple query in Elasticsearch?

```
SELECT * FROM [mytype] WHERE name = alex AND health = good
```

I'm really having troubles with its syntax, multi-match queries don't work in my case, what type of query should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple  `must` clauses in a [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) to combine queries. For example,

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {"name" : "alex"}
                },
                {
                    "term": {"health" : "good"}
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```